# Blank final fields are not initialized when using a super()-constructor

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, super, superclass

I am admittedly a bit new to object-oriented programming and would therefore be very grateful for a little help!
I have a class "Gerade" (German for straight line) and a class "Strahl" (German for ray). I would like to call the constructor of the superclass "Gerade" in the subclass "Strahl". But now I get the error: 'The blank final field p1[and p2] may not have been initialized'. What is the reason for this? I am very grateful for any answers. Thank you in advance!

```
public class Gerade {
    
private final Punkt p1;
private final Punkt p2;

public Gerade(Punkt p1, Punkt p2)
{
    if(p1.equals(p2)==true)
    {
    System.out.println("Die Eingabe ist ungueltig. Beide Punkte haben die selben Koordinaten.");
    p1 = null;
    p2 = null;
    }
    

    if(p1.getXkoord().equals(p2.getXkoord())==true)
    {
        if((p1.getYkoord().compareTo(p2.getYkoord()) < 0))
        {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }
        else
        {
            this.p1 = p2;
            this.p2 = p1;
        }
    }    
    
    else if((p1.getXkoord().compareTo(p2.getXkoord()) > 0))
    {
        this.p2 = p1;
        this.p1 = p2;
    }
    
    else 
    {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }   
}
```

The class "Gerade" uses certain attributes and methods of the class "Punkt". The coordinates are BigDecimals. Just so youre not confused.

```
public class Strahl extends Gerade 
{
    

    private final Punkt p1;
    private final Punkt p2;
    private final Punkt start;


public Strahl(Punkt a, Punkt b)
    {
        super(a, b);
        this.start = a;

    }
```

Comment: I don't speak German, but it looks like your first check is trying to stop you passing in the same point twice. Rather than printing a message (easy to ignore) and nulling out the fields (making the constructed instance useless once you come to use it), throw an exception instead

Answer (score 2):

Both p1 and p2 shall be initialized after constructor of Gerade is executed.  But compiler can not assure  that this will happen  due to complicated control flow.   Look carefully at your conditions -  you have to provide for the fallback if none of if conditions is satisfied

Comment: Alright, I will look over it again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calling `super(a, b)`, there is no reason why you should redeclare them in `Strahl`. Instead of writing `p1.equals(p2) == true`, you can simply write `p1.equals(p2)`.

It can be something as

```
class Gerade {

    private final Punkt p1 = null;
    private final Punkt p2 = null;

    public Gerade(Punkt p1, Punkt p2) {
        if (p1.equals(p2)) {
            System.out.println("Die Eingabe ist ungueltig. Beide Punkte haben die selben Koordinaten.");
            p1 = null;
            p2 = null;
        }

        // ...
    }
}

class Strahl extends Gerade {

    private final Punkt start;

    public Strahl(Punkt a, Punkt b) {
        super(a, b);
        this.start = a;
    }
}
```

I also suggest that you use a constructor only for initialization and any business logic should be refactored into some methods.

Comment: Declaring instance variables as _final_ is a very good practice. You should not encourage them to remove the _final_ keyword.

Comment: Well ... and now, if you see, I answered that already. ;-)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - Yes .

Answer (score 1):

You already have two `Punkt` instance variables in your class `Gerade`. So you do not need to repeat them in your class `Strahl`.

In fact, this is one of the problems: The final variables `p1` and `p2` in `Strahl` are not initialized anywhere!

So, simply remove them:

```
public class Strahl extends Gerade {
    private final Punkt start;
    public Strahl(Punkt a, Punkt b) {
        super(a, b);
        this.start = a;
    }
}
```

Another problem is what @KonstantinPribluda mentioned in his answer.